# Объединение двух таблиц по конкретному столбцу

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

Как грамотно объединить таблицы по столбцу Б?

На примере будет наглядней. У меня есть таблица А и Б, количество строк не совпадает.

Табл. А:

```
   А  Б  
0  1  2  
1  1  3  
2  2  2  
3  2  3  
4  2  1
```

Табл. Б:

```
   Б  В  
0  1  4  
1  2  5  
2  3  6
```

Требуемый результат:

Табл. В:

```
   А  Б  Б  В    
0  1  2  2  5   
1  1  3  3  6   
2  2  2  2  5   
3  2  3  3  6   
4  2  1  1  4
```

Как вы сами понимаете, мне требуется "подтянуть" значения из столбца В.
В SQL это решается просто, но как это можно сделать в питоне?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это оч. просто:

```
In [439]: A.merge(B)
Out[439]:
   А  Б  В
0  1  2  5
1  2  2  5
2  1  3  6
3  2  3  6
4  2  1  4
```

PS по умолчанию метод [DataFrame.merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) объединяет таблицы (`DataFrame'ы`) по столбцам с совпадающими названиями. Также столбец(ы) для объединения можно указать явно, воспользовавшись параметрами:

- `on`
- `left_on`
- `right_on`

[Официальная документация о различных способах объединения данных в Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html)

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогло